# Import Powershell Cmdlet Results to Existing Google Sheet

Tags: google-drive-api

first-timer here. I couldn't seem to find anything relevant when I searched for this, and perhaps it's because I'm over-thinking it. Here is what I have:

1. We have a Google Sheet that contains data manually copied from an Excel CSV.
2. This data comes from a Powershell Cmdlet that queries our entire Exchange Environment and returns all mailbox sizes.
3. I need to find a way to export the data resulting from this Cmdlet directly to a *new tab* in the already existing spreadsheet.

This might be a rudimentary request, so anything that you see that I need to learn in order to  accomplish this will be taken seriously. I'm assuming I need to call the Google API somehow and feed the resulting data through it to Google Sheets. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: The way I've figured it in my head is that I need to script the cmdlet to:

1. Run the cmdlet
2. Export the CSV
3. Upload the CSV to Google Drive
4. Import the uploaded CSV to the existing sheet

Is there an easier/better way? Thanks!